# what does the "<" and ">" do in formatting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

In the Python documentation, it says that the alignment `'<'` forces the field to be left-aligned within the available space.

Does that mean that this line of code aligns each variable 10 spaces apart or at least 10 spaces?

```
print("{:<10} {:<10} {:<10} £{:<10} £{:<10}".format(GTIN,product,Quantity,indprice,finprice))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<10` formatting makes each field *at least* 10 characters wide, putting the `str()` conversion of the value in the left portion of the field. So a value of `'foo'` (3 characters long) is going to end up with 7 more spaces to the right to create a string of 10 characters, and that's the string that fills that replaces the `{..}` field.

If the value requires more than 10 characters, then that field will be replaced with the full text for the value; the width is a *minimum* length, not a maximum.

So each `{:<10}` field is replaced by something that is at least 10 characters wide, using spaces to make up the difference on the right of the value.

Demo, filling a value into a field left-aligned with a minimum width of 5:

```
>>> for value in ('f', 'foo', 'foobar'):
...     formatted = '>{:<5}<'.format(value)
...     print(len(value), len(formatted), formatted)
...
1 7 >f    <
3 7 >foo  <
6 8 >foobar<
```

The value is left-aligned into the minimum field width, but `foobar` is longer so the total output length of the field grew to match.

Comment: What I still don't understand is if I have an 8 digit number e.g "35619833" , why does it create 3 spaces in front of the number and not 2 ?

Comment: @Dolodo.RS: see those spaces *between* the `{..}` fields? Those are literal  spaces, they are not part of the `{..}` fields and are included in the output literally.

Comment: @Dolodo.RS: they are no different from the `>` and `<` characters in my demo, or the `£` pound symbols in your string.